# $PSPACE$ not equal $DSPACE(2^n) $

Tags: complexity-theory

It seems pretty obvious that $PSPACE$ is not equal to $DSPACE(2^n) $. Can this be shown using the space hierarchy theorem? Is that the most simple and straight-forward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tempting to use the following argument: For every $k$, the space hierarchy theorem shows that there is some problem in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(2^n)$ which is not in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n^k)$ (since $n^k = o(2^n)$), hence $\mathrm{PSPACE} \neq \mathrm{DSPACE}(2^n)$. Unfortunately, the same argument shows that $\mathrm{PSPACE} \neq \mathrm{PSPACE}$, since for every $k$ there is a problem in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n^{k+1}) \subset \mathrm{PSPACE}$ which is not in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n^k)$ (since $n^k = o(n^{k+1})$).

What went wrong? Hopefully this will be clear later on.

How do we fix this argument? Take a (space-constructible) function $f(n)$ such that

1. $f(n) = o(2^n)$.
2. For every $k$, $n^k = O(f(n))$.

For example, we could take $f(n) = 1.5^n$.

The space hierarchy theorem gives a language in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(2^n)$ which is not in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(n))$. This language is not in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n^k)$ for any $k$, hence it is not in $\mathrm{PSPACE}$.

Notice that in contrast to the preceding argument, here the *same* language works for *every* $k$; there we got a *different* language for each $k$.

Comment: The context of this answer is that I originally answered with a bogus proof based on a weakened version of the time hierarchy theorem ("for all $f$, for all $g$, $g=o(f)$ implies that there is a language in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(g(n))\setminus\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(n))$"). Yuval's $1.5^n$ trick allows $\mathrm{PSPACE}\subset\mathrm{DSPACE}(2^n)$ to be proven from that weak version of time hierarchy. The correct version of time hierarchy is "For all $f$, there exists a language $L\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(f)$ such that, for all $g$, $g=o(f)$ implies that $L\notin\mathrm{DSPACE}(g)$.

Comment: (A corollary is that this answer is much more complicated than it needs to be.)

Answer (score 2):

> Can this be shown using the space hierarchy theorem?

Yes. By the space hierarchy theorem, there is a language $L\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(2^n)$ that is not in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(n))$ for any $f=o(2^n)$.  In particular, this language is not in $\mathrm{DSPACE}(n^k)$ for any $k$, so it is not in $\mathrm{PSPACE}$.

> Is that the most simple and straight-forward way?

It's hard to imagine anything simpler!